# How to get ROBOCOPY to throw an error when there's denied access

Tags: robocopy

I am using ROBOCOPY to copy some files from folder A to folder B.  I have purposefully made folder B inaccessible using NTFS permission to throw an error so that it can take a different action when copy is failed. However it seems that ROBOCOPY is not throwing a errorlevel that is above 0 or 1 (Success). 
Using Server 2016 with admin level CMD.

Script that I am using:

```
@echo on

:: Robocopy's Variables
set source=\\computer1\folder1\
set destination=\\computer2\folder2\
set logfilelocation=C:\scriptfolder\log.txt
set scripts=C:\scriptfolder

robocopy %source% %destination% /E /NFL /NDL /NC /NS /NP /W:1 /R:0 /LOG:%logfilelocation%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto success
if ERRORLEVEL 0 goto success

:FAIL
call %scripts%\failed.bat
goto end

:SUCCESS
call %scripts%\success.bat

:END
```

So basically, if I run echo %errorlevel% after the robocopy line, it throws a errorlevel of 0 (success) while the log shows access denied for all files.

```
2018/08/27 10:22:52 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\computer2\folder2\
Access is denied.
```

I wanted an error, but just not giving me ROBOCOPY errorlevel higher than 1.  Any suggestions so I can take action when the files do not copy?

Comment: Could it be that the "no log" parameters that you specify, `/NFL /NDL /NC /NS`, also cause the errors to be ignored?

Comment: Same issue here. IMHO this is a bug, I'm just not sure where to report it yet :D

Answer (score 0):

Identical, for me, when using switches /R:1 /W:2, it also returns an errorlevel of 0 - if I do not supply any switches, I need to break the retry, I then get an errorlevel of -1073741510 - which, according to the link below, means the user just aborted the script execution.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/93b658c7-7235-4818-b0e7-23eaf406d089/the-process-exit-code-was-quot1073741510?forum=sqlintegrationservices

I guess I’ll have to write some code that tests access first.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1102555)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, yes, you are right - my answer doesn’t answer the questions; I believe it to be a bug with robocopy that cannot be answered. My answer was really an effort to bump the original query whilst adding extra details. As my comment states: even when adding switches /R:1 {Retry once} and then breaking out of the wait - Robocopy returns an errorlevel of zero when the target destination is write-protected or otherwise unavailable. I want to report the issue as a bug but do not know how to. Other than using the Windows Feedback option built into windows 10. I have now done this.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by using the dir command to check for accessibility:

```
set srcdir=\\myserver\myshare

dir %srcdir% > nul
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 set ermsg=Problem accessing %srcdir% & goto reporterr

robocopy %srcdir% %destdir%

:reporterr
rem skipped robocopy and do stuff when dir errors
echo %ermsg%
```